# Facebook Login Using FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, authentication

I am using the following code to present the user with the Facebook Embedded WebView Dialog in an iOS 7 app

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email"]];
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
}];
```

On my development iPad, I see the Facebook dialog and login view just fine.  On iPhone, the dialog fills the screen just fine, but the spinning progress indicator just sits there forever.  Our QA team is seeing the never ending spinning progress indicator on both devices.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  I am about to give up and just implement the Mobile Safari Login Dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
```

and it works for me.

**EDIT**:  You may also want to check to make sure you have the Advanced setting "Embedded Browser OAuth Login" turned on for you Facebook app.

Comment: This works when I am running in debug mode on a device, but as soon as I make an ad-hoc distribution build and install on a device, the same thing happens.

Comment: I didn't have the Embedded Browser setting turned on.  Now it works!  Thanks!